# How can I use the "#redirect to '/path'" method in a ternary condition?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am dealing with different routes in my Sinatra controller file that #redirect to other routes under a condition.
However, I want to clean up code and save space with a ternary condition instead of a full if/else/end condition.

My question is how can I turn this:

```
if Helpers.is_logged_in?(session)
   erb :"tweets/show"
else 
   redirect to "/login"
end
```

Into this:

```
Helpers.is_logged_in?(session) ? erb(:"tweets/show") : redirect to "/login"
```

Without the #redirect to "/path" method causing a SyntaxError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Helpers.is_logged_in?(session) ? erb(:"tweets/show") : redirect("/login")
```

or

```
(Helpers.is_logged_in? session) ? (erb :"tweets/show") : (redirect "/login")
```

I prefer the former between these two; but I strongly prefer your original code over either. "Saving space" in source code (aside from DRYing) is not a meaningful pursuit except in obfuscation contests.